# Is the Intel® IPP Asynchronous C/C++ library included in the standard IPP library?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, intel-ipp

I have queried directly with Intel which is still pending.
Basically I have searched the internet quite rigorously but have been unable to determine if the asynchronous library described [here](http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/3727/ipp_async_get_started.htm) is available as part of the library downloaded from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp).

Note: I have actually installed Student version of [Intel Parallel Studio XE Cluster Edition for windows](https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software/student), which as far as I can tell includes the ipp library linked above.

I intend to use the library as part of OpenCV-3.0, which I have successfully built without ipp_a for the time being [using cmake](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).

My end goal for now is to be able to run [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_use_ippa_conversion/how_to_use_ippa_conversion.html#howtouseippaconversion) successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel responded, and it appears as though the asynchronous functionality is NOT included in ipp as of yet, which is a shame. Their response on the developer zone forum was as follows:

"The asynchronous library is preview library, and it is not available in IPP now.

The Preview releases were intended to solicit community feedback about the features, and it  may change based on community feedback.  At this time, there are no features in the IPP preview packages are included in the IPP, and the prior packages are no longer available.

While that package is not there,  IPP offers the IPPCV package, which provides the CPU optimization for some OpenCV functions:

please check the new OpenCV 3.0 documentation on this: 
http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0.html

a subset of Intel IPP (IPPCV) is given to us and our users free of charge, free of licensing fees, for commercial and non-commerical use. It’s used by default in x86 and x64 builds on Windows, Linux and Mac."

Link to the forum here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-integrated-performance-primitives/topic/594325#comment-1841423